# Changing iframe src by url

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a typical website with a menubar and some tabs. On the bottom is an iframe where it displays the main content. When a tab is clicked, it uses the iframe as a target to change the page.

Is there a way to redirect the iframe via the main page's url? Right now when I navigate through the site, the url never changes, but it would be nice to have a way to directly link to a page.

I'm open to changing things around, maybe I didn't set it up the best way. It would also be nice to avoid any JavaScript solutions if possible.

Comment: Please explain the down & close vote!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event))` to keep track of changes on the url and `location.hash` to get the hash that was input in it.

I also had to use `iframe.contentWindow.location.replace(newPage.html)` to make sure that going back and forward works ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the url with `window.location`.

For example:

```
if(window.location.pathname == "/profile"){
     document.getElementById("iframe").src = "./profile.html";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a try.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if that answered your question!